# Does mass affects accelleration of an object in a sloapy movement?

Tags: classical-mechanics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Would a light or a heavy ball roll fastest down a slope?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/19552/would-a-light-or-a-heavy-ball-roll-fastest-down-a-slope)

Is there a change of the accelleration of an object moving on a sloapy plane if the mass is changed?

Comment: I didn't know the existence of this site...

Comment: What does "sloapy" mean?

Comment: I'm going to kill this on in favor of the more accurately explained following one.